# How to structure a cordova app using ngcordova WITHOUT ionic?

Tags: cordova, ngcordova

I am PRETTY NEW to Cordova. I see the Cordova Hello World dir structure is:

```
C:\1d\CrossPlatformPjs\CordovaPjs\cordovaTutTake2Pj\workshop\www>dir /s /b
C:\1d\CrossPlatformPjs\CordovaPjs\cordovaTutTake2Pj\workshop\www\css
C:\1d\CrossPlatformPjs\CordovaPjs\cordovaTutTake2Pj\workshop\www\img
C:\1d\CrossPlatformPjs\CordovaPjs\cordovaTutTake2Pj\workshop\www\index.html
C:\1d\CrossPlatformPjs\CordovaPjs\cordovaTutTake2Pj\workshop\www\js
C:\1d\CrossPlatformPjs\CordovaPjs\cordovaTutTake2Pj\workshop\www\css\index.css
C:\1d\CrossPlatformPjs\CordovaPjs\cordovaTutTake2Pj\workshop\www\img\logo.png
C:\1d\CrossPlatformPjs\CordovaPjs\cordovaTutTake2Pj\workshop\www\js\index.js
```

Where should i put ngCordova WITHOUT using Ionic? I am concerned about Ionic's Licensing requirements. Does anyone have a simple starter example? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you install `ngcordova` with `bower` like it is mentioned in the [docs](http://ngcordova.com/docs/install/). `bower` is a package manager for the frontend like installing `node` packages. You can provide a `.bowerrc` file in your root project folder to specify the installation path for packages (see [docs](http://bower.io/docs/config/)). For example:

```
{
  "directory": "www\lib"
}
```

This could also be your directory to put your source files of `ngcordova`. With `bower` you can simply install `ngcordova` by typing:

```
bower install ngcordova
```

But you have to install `bower` globally first:

```
npm install -g bower
```

**Further explanation:**

You should put your frontend packages into your `\www` folder, because this folder is reproduced within each platform's subdirectory according to the [cordova documentation](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/index.html#link-4).

> The *www* source directory is reproduced within each platform's subdirectory, appearing for example in `platforms/ios/www` or `platforms/android/assets/www`.

This assures you to have your dependencies available on each platform to run your application it without any circumstances...

Comment: Two Questions. QUESTION-1 Having already installed bower, in my example, your .bowerrc goes in parent of www == ...\workshop? Q-2 then I cd into ...\workshop and run   > bower install ngcordova    --> which will put ngCordova into the not yet existing ...\www\lib dir?

Comment: **Q1**: .`bowerrc` goes into your root dir ergo into `\workshop` **Q2**.: Yes, this should be working so far

Comment: For sake of completeness, don't forget to include `ngCordova` in your `index.html` → `<script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

Here's what i discovered. Thanks, Beat, for getting me started.

In my example, `...\workshop`is the Project directory.

So with bower installed:

In the Project Directory == `...\workshop`, create the file named .bowerrc (note [double quotes, forward slashes]) ==

```
{
  "directory": "www/lib/"
}
```

Then with the Project Directory == `...workshop`,

```
> cd C:\1d\CrossPlatformPjs\CordovaPjs\cordovaTutTake2Pj\workshop
> bower install ngCordova
bower ngCordova#*               cached git://github.com/driftyco/ng-cordova.git#0.1.23-alpha
bower ngCordova#*             validate 0.1.23-alpha against git://github.com/driftyco/ng-cordova.git#*
bower angular#>= 1.2.23         cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.4.8
bower angular#>= 1.2.23       validate 1.4.8 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#>= 1.2.23
bower ngCordova#~0.1.23-alpha  install ngCordova#0.1.23-alpha
bower angular#>= 1.2.23        install angular#1.4.8

ngCordova#0.1.23-alpha www\lib\ngCordova
└── angular#1.4.8

angular#1.4.8 www\lib\angular

>C:\1d\CrossPlatformPjs\CordovaPjs\cordovaTutTake2Pj\workshop>dir www\lib
 Volume in drive C is Windows
 Volume Serial Number is F2FB-4810

 Directory of C:\1d\CrossPlatformPjs\CordovaPjs\cordovaTutTake2Pj\workshop\www\lib

12/16/2015  03:18 PM    <DIR>          .
12/16/2015  03:18 PM    <DIR>          ..
12/16/2015  03:18 PM    <DIR>          angular
12/16/2015  03:18 PM    <DIR>          ngCordova
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
           4 Dir(s)  891,966,029,824 bytes free

C:\1d\CrossPlatformPjs\CordovaPjs\cordovaTutTake2Pj\workshop>
```

Thanks again, Beat.

Comment: I added further explanation i forget about it to answer your question fully